# Specific considerations when using pm2 cluster mode to launch node.js app

Tags: node.js, pm2

I would really like to use cluster mode to do some basic load balancing for my node.js app but I haven't found any documentation about special considerations when running in cluster mode. Are there any special modifications that need to be made to ones code when running in cluster mode? I would assume all node endpoints will be executed atomically but I haven't found any info about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that much/any of the codebase would be executed any differently let alone atomically, it depends on the OS/hardware more than a process manager like pm2.

There's no need for you to change anything in your code to use pm2's cluster mode, just use the `-i` flag and set to the desired number (usually the number of available physical CPUs available on the system. Usually you can do `pm2 start --name MyApp -i $(nproc)` otherwise you can manually do it in your code using the [cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) module.

Assuming `var cluster = require('cluster')` you can change the scheduling<sup>[link](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster_schedulingpolicy)</sup> method by setting `cluster.schedulingPolicy` to `cluster.SCHED_RR` if you want Round Robin scheduling or `cluster.SCHED_NONE` if you want the OS to choose the scheduling.

Comment: Ok thanks for the feedback. I have been starting it with pm2 start --name appName -i 0 to use all available cpus. My old colleague had been worried we would have some unexpected results if we ever switched to cluster mode so I just wanted to see if anyone else had any experience running this on a live server.

Comment: I've got loads of apps out in the wild managed by PM2 and in cluster mode, have instances of neural networks in cluster mode as well and it works well. If performance is really the concern you might consider switching to a faster language like Go or Rust though :)

Comment: I tried using cluster mode with my existing code requiring socket.io and it wss not working as sessions wore getting lost untill i appened NODE 
 process instance to the port: https.createServer(app).listen(port + (process.env.NODE_APP_INSTANCE ? parseInt(process.env.NODE_APP_INSTANCE) : 0),  () => {....});

This works for me however i am stil bit spectical that will it using load balancing algorithm or it will only run on first instance only.